# Clearing floats with CSS and IE7?

Tags: internet-explorer, html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've been banging my head for a day trying to get floats and clears to work properly in older versions of Internet Explorer. I've read numerous tutorials on using .clear:after trick, etc. but I can't get anything to actually work!

I have HTML like this:

```
<div id="section">
  <h2>Section Title</h2>

  <label for="name">Name</label>
  <input type="text" id="name" />

  <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
  <input type="text" id="dob" />

  <label for="email">Email</label>
  <input type="text" id="email" />
</div>
```

And CSS like this:

```
#section {border:solid 2px #b7ddf2; background:#ebf4fb; margin-top: 20px;}
#label{clear: left; float: left; width: 300px; margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
#input{float: left; margin-bottom: 10px;}
```

In modern browsers e.g. Opera 25, The displays as follows:

```
Name            [Name field]
Date of birth   [Date of birth field]
Email           [Email]
```

In older versions of Internet explorer (6 or 7), it displays as:

```
Name            [Name field] [Date of birth field] [Email field]
Date of birth
E-mail
```

I'm keen not to adjust my HTML, can anyone help me with a CSS fix?

Comment: I would change the HTML. I mean, for the sake of `<label for="name">Name</label>  <input type="text" id="name" /> </div style="clear:both;" ></div>`

Comment: Thanks, I know I can fix this by adding extra DIVs into the HTML, but I'm keen to avoid that unless there is no other option.

Comment: This is a question for stackoverflow.com, and you have an account there.

Comment: @CraigJohnstone: Did you get a chance to test the code from my answer? I'm pretty sure this is the only way to do what you are asking. Floating elements are not handled correctly in IE 6/7 which is why these workarounds are needed. Also my solution has the advantage in that all browsers other than IE6 and IE7 will ignore the workaround.

Comment: @SachaK, thanks - I agree entirely. I'm not sure how this ended up on superuser. I've hadn't heard of superuser until now and thought I *was* posting on stackoverflow until I noticed your comment and checked the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to do is a bad idea as firstly no one should be making this much effort to support IE6 in a new web application and secondly your HTML structure is not flexible and will only work in very specific scenario.

However, I was curious to see if the classic IE6 float bugs could be overcome purely with CSS and no extra HTML and surprisingly it does seem possible. The trick is to use IE's CSS expressions to inject <br> elements in to the page after the text boxes.

The following code worked for me in IETester when emulating IE6 and IE7:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            #section {border:solid 2px #b7ddf2; background:#ebf4fb; margin-top: 20px; display: block; zoom: 1}
            label{clear: left; float: left; width: 300px; margin-left: 20px; margin-bottom: 10px;}
            input{
                float: left;
                margin-bottom: 10px; 
                *zoom: expression(this.runtimeStyle.zoom="1", 
                    this.parentNode.insertBefore(document.createElement("br"), this.nextSibling).style.cssText="clear:both;font:0/0 serif");
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="section">
            <h2>Section Title</h2>

                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" id="name" />


                <label for="dob">Date of Birth</label>
                <input type="text" id="dob" />


                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" id="email" />

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Based on information from [this page](http://nicolasgallagher.com/better-float-containment-in-ie/)

Comment: Thanks - that solution worked fine. It doesn't quite solve the problem of achieving it without adding additional markup (as the CSS adds a BR), but I can't find any other way of doing it - so I guess that's the only solution. Cheers.